# unbalanced avl tree check function

Tags: c++, data-structures, avl-tree

I'm implementing an AVL tree and wrote that function that will calculate the balance factor of a given tree:

```
int avlTree::balanceFactor(avlNode *tree){
     return height(tree->left) - height(tree->right);
 }
```

but it seems like while indeed return me the right balance factor of the tree, it won't let me determine weather the tree is AVL balanced, because according to defintion, for every sub tree the balance factor should be checked. i.e that tree:

[image]

would have, according to the function a balance factor of 0, which doesn't give me a lot when it comes to balancig the tree. what can i add?

Answer (score 0):

Your `balanceFactor` function is correct. You just apply it to nodes starting from the root, going down the chain of unbalanced nodes, as described [here, for example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).